# Reading data to make adjacency list with two weights

Tags: c++, input, adjacency-matrix, adjacency-list

I'm making an adjacency list to represent a graph of roads, there are two kinds of weights (length and capacity) and for some reason this code never exits the for loop. it gets stuck on the cin for the last line. input is in the form:

4 5 4 
0 1 1 5 
0 2 1 4 
1 2 2 2 
1 3 1 4 
2 3 1 5

I'm a student starting out. Help is very much appreciated thank you.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int N, M, T; //#cities N, #highways M, time available T

struct Road {
    int Y, L, C; //destination Y, length L and capacity C
};

void readNetwork(vector<vector<Road>> &adjList) {
    cin >> N >> M >> T;
    adjList.resize(N);
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++){
        int x, y, l, c;
        cin >> x >> y >> l >> c;
        adjList[x].push_back({y,l,c});
    }
}

int main() {
    
    vector<vector<Road>> adjList;

    readNetwork(adjList);
    cout << adjList.size();

    return 0;
};
```

Comment: How did you determine it got stuck? Did your debugger tell you that? It looks just fine here.

Comment: is the "/" supposed to be there? i ran your code in the compiler, putting your input in a file without that slash and it outputted "4"

Comment: It worked for me. I suggest you add some `cout` statements to print out the values that you read from the cin and also before that to indicate that it's waiting for your input. As a side note, what does the variable `T` do? And why do you have `\` at the end of the input?